# Turn stream into function argument to use Telnet and Ncurses

Tags: c++, c, sockets, telnet, ncurses

Hello fellow programmers.

I'm developing a C/C++ program with sockets that are supposed to connect to the server via Telnet.

To send text and ANSI codes to the Telnet remote terminal I'm using this funcion:

```
void writeline(int socketfd, string line)
{
  string tosend = line + "\n";
  write(socketfd, tosend.c_str(), tosend.length());
}
```

**Is there a way to create a stream object like cout, cerr, clog or even a FILE (from C) that sends everything it gets to a function?**

For example:

```
clientout << "Hello World";
```

would call something like this:

```
writeline(clientout.str()); //or alike
```

I did something like this last year when I programmed a microprocessor (with AVR) and redirected stdout into a function that sent everything to the USART connection. I was hoping I could do something like that now.

This is how I did it then:

```
static int usart_putchar(char c, FILE *stream)
{
    while ( !(UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)) );
    UDR0 = c;
    return 0;
}

static FILE usart_stream = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(usart_putchar, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);

int main()
{
   //(...)
   stdout = &usart_stream;
   //(...)
}
```

I'm interested in this because, besides being an easier way to print into the remote terminal, I need a stream for even thinking about using ncurses with my program. To use it, I need [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36880/newterm-3curses.html) function which needs a stream for input and another for output.

I apologize for the long question.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do this, but it's quite a bit of work.

Basically, you have to implement a subclass of `std::streambuf` that implements `std::streambuf`'s virtual methods to read and write from the socket directly, or call the wrapper functions you showed in your question. It's not ***really*** a lot of work, it's only a handful of virtual methods, but you have to understand their obscure semantics, and implement them correctly, 100%. No margin for error.

Once you have your `std::streambuf` subclass, you can then instantiate a `std::istream`, `std::ostream`, and/or `std::iostream` (which have a constructor that takes a pointer to a `std::streambuf`).

Now, you have your stream that reads and/or writes to the socket.

Comment: I see. Is there any way to get the "FILE" from a "streabuf"? It's just that ncurses isn't made for c++. The definition of the function is "SCREEN *newterm(char *type, FILE *outfd, FILE *infd)". Thank you.

Comment: I've checked every protected virtual funcion in streambuf but couldn't understand how to implpement what you said. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/     could you tell me how I can do it?

Comment: You don't need to give me the step by step solution. I just need to know some informations so I can start looking for an answer by myself. So if you know how this could be done, please shed some light on the matter for me.

Answer (score -1):

Could you use boost asio?

See example of using `posix::stream_descriptor` to implement a chat application http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/posix_chat_client.cpp

Comment: This is not what was asked.